# Ubuntu local repository results "Hash Sum mismatch" error

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I am using a local repository server to update all Linux flavors, in that I have configured Ubuntu 20 server to update Ubuntu 20 servers as well, which started giving below error recently. Tried deleting contents of folder "`rm -rf /var/lib/apt`" found as a solution from another thread.

I have tried manually delete the `Commands-amd64.xz` from local repo as found there is mismatch in hash, and then ran curl command to download it again which resolves my issue. But it re-occured when it sync the repo again from Ubuntu main repository as per daily schedule.

```
curl -o Commands-amd64.xz http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/68a13b187a08d10f59ed448a305317ca202fd001ac2c62b18f851853c29fc6d5
```

**Error Snips:**

```
    Get:48 https://localIPaddress/ubuntu20/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [580 B]
Fetched 23.9 MB in 3s (6,846 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://<localserverIP>/ubuntu20/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:14840 [weak]
    - SHA256:68a13b187a08d10f59ed448a305317ca202fd001ac2c62b18f851853c29fc6d5
    - SHA1:dd6e6a72880a22a264a7a40bca6cd9e8ec4dbbbf [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4917444606f7c42d4579abfaddddfbe4 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:75d0ec77f608b4ed82a8863208eb909deefe518143a2faa1a38b386541306304
    - SHA1:b9c4e3efbce29c5701b8889872091ab943b92240 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:080f9750feeef30269fed50447a5922a [weak]
    - Filesize:14840 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Mon, 21 Mar 2022 17:17:39 +0000
   Release file created at: Mon, 21 Mar 2022 15:10:25 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov for the edit, really need to get in to more about formatting..

Answer (score 1):

I use apt-mirror (https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror) for local 18.04 and 20.04 repositories. I was experiencing the same issue of hash sum mismatches and file size mismatches for Commands-amd64.xz files. Solved by downloading Release files immediately after doing a mirror sync. My postmirror.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/ubuntu_repo/mirror
for p in {focal,bionic}{,-{backports,updates}}/{main,restricted,universe,multiverse};do >&2 echo "${p}"
  wget -q -r "http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz"
  wget -q -r "http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}/cnf/Commands-i386.xz"
done
for p in {focal-security,bionic-security}/{main,restricted,universe,multiverse};do >&2 echo "${p}"
  wget -q -r "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz"
  wget -q -r "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}/cnf/Commands-i386.xz"
done
for p in {focal,bionic}{,-{backports,updates}}/{Release,InRelease,Release.gpg};do >&2 echo "${p}"
  wget -q -r "http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}"
done
for p in {focal-security,bionic-security}/{Release,InRelease,Release.gpg};do >&2 echo "${p}"
  wget -q -r "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/${p}"
done
```

The repos I mirror from are for Azure Ubuntu. Replace them with the repositories you use.